# MQTT Over Websockets in Android

Tags: android, websocket, mqtt, wss

I am using Paho Android Service for MQTT over web sockets.

https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-client-library-enyclopedia-paho-android-service

My question is how do I set the Broker WSS URI which has a query parameter in it.

For example: **wss://test.amazon.com:80/mqtt?query1=value&query2=value**

**Edit**

If we add the complete URL, the PAHO client library throws following exception:

```
MqttException (0) - java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toLowerCase()' on a null object reference
W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ExceptionHelper.createMqttException(ExceptionHelper.java:38)
W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:664)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toLowerCase()' on a null object reference
W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.websocket.WebSocketHandshake.receiveHandshakeResponse(WebSocketHandshake.java:133)
W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.websocket.WebSocketHandshake.execute(WebSocketHandshake.java:74)
W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.websocket.WebSocketSecureNetworkModule.start(WebSocketSecureNetworkModule.java:77)
W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:650)
```

**Edit 2**

```
CLIENT = new MqttAndroidClient(this, "wss://test.amazon.com:80/mqtt?query1=value&query2=value", clientId, new MemoryPersistence());
CLIENT.setCallback(this);

MQTT_CONNECTION_OPTIONS = new MqttConnectOptions();
MQTT_CONNECTION_OPTIONS.setCleanSession(true);

try {
    IMqttToken token = CLIENT.connect(MQTT_CONNECTION_OPTIONS);
    token.setActionCallback(new IMqttActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
            Log.v("tag", "onsuccess");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    });


} catch (MqttException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: What happens if you just specify that URL as the connection URL? Show your code and any errors that are thrown

Comment: Include your code where you set up the connection, but if that's correct then this is a bug in the Paho code (it should fail a lot more gracefully than that0

Comment: Added the code part for connect.

Comment: Open a defect against the Paho client

Answer (score 3):

Changing version from

compile 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:**1.1.0**'

to

compile 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:**1.2.0**'

resolved this issue. They have fixed this issue in v1.2.0